# FFMpeg monitoring an rtmp feed

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

I am looking to use FFMpeg to monitor a live stream (rtmp) so I can use blackdetect or freezedetect on it.  Can someone help me understand how to get ffmpeg to monitor an rtmp stream?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i rtmp://input -vf blackdetect -f null -`

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  Is there a way to use this and then create a notification if black frames of a livestream are detected?  I was thinking of using the ffmpeg-python wrapper.

Comment: What kind of notification?

Comment: Basically, I want to monitor our live stream to make sure the encoder does't freeze or stop.  Therefore, I wanted to read the stream with blackdetect and freezedetect and if there is blackdetect > 9 seconds, then I would send an SNS or email notification.  

Thank you so much for your help so far.  I am making progress.

Comment: This is a really broad question. It may get more attention if you make 1 separate question per topic: How to monitor a feed (which my comment mostly answered), How to send notification, etc.

Comment: Thank you, llogan.  I will do that.  I appreciate your help.